# Java - JSON serialize - expiry date: "12/28" to "12\/28" i.e. escape forward slash

Tags: java, json, serialization

In Java, I want to serialize a JSON string containing values such as `12/28` to `12\/28`

Using Apache lib StringEscapeUtils and then for serialization, using jackson lib, output comes out as `12\\/28`:
**Current output:**

```
{
"expiryDate": "12\\/28"
}
```

However, I want the output to be "12/28"
**Desired output:**

```
{
"expiryDate": "12\/28"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried anything with any library ?

Comment: Using apache commons libs: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson() to escape forward slash
And to serialize the object to string, using jackson-databind lib, converting to string

Comment: can you add the code in the question

Comment: `\/` is not a valid Json escape sequence. Most Json parsers will read `"12\/28"` as string `12/28`.

Comment: Why do you need to use StringEscapeUtils ? And why do want to have the backslash in the output? Won't a Json parser just turn that back into a single forward slash again?

Comment: There is no need for any of this. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

According to the JSON specification (e.g. the syntax graphs at http://json.org), `\/` is a valid JSON escape sequence.

However the sequence `\/` means the the same thing as `/`, so there is little point in using `\/`.   (A conformant JSON parser will read it as a `/`.)

I <strike>am not</strike> was not aware of any JSON library that will output a `/` as `\/` when serializing data to JSON.  However, it appears that json-simple ([link](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple), [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)) always escapes a `/` as `\/`:

- I don't know why they decided to do that.
- The code that implements this behavior is in the method `org.json.simple.JSONValue`.

On the other hand, I am not aware of a JSON library that *won't* escape a literal `\` in a string when it sees one.  (That would be broken, IMO, unless it was part of a design feature for stitching together already formatted JSON string fragments.)

Answer (score -1):

After exploring some options, was able to achieve desired output using below.

Library used:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
```

Code Sample:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("expiryDate", "12/28");
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
```

Output:

```
{"expiryDate":"12\/28"}
```